# No puedo poner la barra de navegación completamente de un color

Tags: css, css3, navbar

Estoy haciendo un proyecto en MVC ASP .Net y la barra de navegación si cambia de color pero no el header completo sino solamente una parte y esteticamente se ve fatal, ¿como se puede solucionar?. He intentado poner body background color y me cambia completamente el color de toda la pagina,
les adjunto mi hoja de estilos y una imagen de ejemplo.

```
 #barranav-principal {
      background-color: #1aa877;
    }

    li {
      position: relative;
      padding-left: 11px;
      margin: 0 0 4px 0;
     }
    /*Fuente de la barnav*/

    ul {
     list-style-type: none;
    }   

    a {
     color: #1aa877;
     text-decoration: none; /* no underline */
      }

     .wrapper {
    border: 2px solid green;
    [![}


    #nav-dropdown {
        padding-top: 20px;
    }

    #dropdownMenuButton {
        padding-top: 20px;
        padding-bottom: 20px;
        color: white;
        text-decoration: none;
    }

    p {
        font-size: 18px;
    }
    header {
        background-color: #1aa877;
        border-color: #1aa877;
    }
```

Y Aqui esta el html de la barra de navegacion, actualmente estoy usando la carpeta compartida para usar el mismo overlay en las paginas que desee, en mi caso solo segui la estructura que ya estaba por defecto en la barra de navegacion default y solamente añadi el dropdown button y una imagen pero no puedo conseguir que el color de fondo del header sea completamente verde sino que hay bordes muy grandes blancos

```
 <header>

    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
        <div class="container-fluid" id="barranav-principal">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                <a asp-area="" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Pagina_Alumno" class="navbar-"><img src="~/images/Logos/source/logo-corto.png" style="width: 100px" /></a>
            </div>



            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
                <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto" id="ul-general">
                    <li class="nav-item dropdown" id="nav-dropdown">
                        <button class="btn btn-lg btn-link dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenuButton" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                            Explorar
                        </button>

                        <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu" role="menu" 76">

                            <a class="dropdown-item" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Calificaciones_Alumnos">Calificaciones</a><br />
                            <a class="dropdown-item" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Examenes_Alumnos">Exámenes</a>
                            <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                            <a class="dropdown-item" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Cuenta_Alumno">Mi cuenta</a><br />
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Cerrar sesión</a>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                </ul>






            </div>

        </div>
    </nav>

</header>
```

Aqui una imagen de como se ve

https://i.stack.imgur.com/kPVd8.png

Comment: Si lo que quieres cambiar de color son lo bordes blancos de la barra de navegación, puedes dejar el margin de la barra en 0

Comment: Hola @Alexis. Por favor, lee https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example  Estaría bien que añadas parte de tu html para que podamos reproducir el problema fácilmente